# Using listadd in another sql filter ocndition in oracle

Tags: oracle12c, listagg

I am using oracle 12c and I am in need of knowing listagg function and its result usage in another sql.
I have a table called TRACKING with a column ID. I am using below sql to the list of ids.

```
SELECT LISTAGG (id, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY id)        
        FROM TRACKING;
```

Result is: 2005900604,2005900605.
Now I am trying to pass this result to another sql dynamically like:

```
select sum(col_a) from table_a where col_b in (2005900604,2005900605); //want to pass the result of listagg dynamically.
```

I am trying as below:

```
PROCEDURE computeTotal ()
   IS
      p_id   number;

   BEGIN
      SELECT LISTAGG (id, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY id)  into p_id         
        FROM TRACKING;

      select sum(col_a) from table_a where col_b in (p_id); END;
```

I am getting an error while execute this as

```
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error
```

please guide me to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

That won't work, as p_id is a single string value and not a list of discreet IDs.

Instead do it like this:

```
select sum(col_a) from table_a where col_b in (select id from tracking);
```

or

```
select sum(a.col_a) from table_a a join tracking t on t.id = a.col_b;
```

Note: the second option only works correctly if tracking.id is guaranteed to be unique.